# How can i update latitude, longitude and properties for one point without erasing and recreating all points

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular7, geojson, ngx-leaflet

I use on Angular 7 :

@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^5.0.2" with  "leaflet": "^1.5.1"

I have one probleme : i want update juste one specific point position and his properties without erase all points.

For example : i have one geoJSON file :

```
[
    {
        "attribution": "AT_101000",
        "recordid": "101000",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry":{
            "coordinates": [5.4933266666667, 43.471425],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties":{
            "label": "BT 9999844",
            "latitude": 43.471425,
            "longitude": 5.4933266666667
        }
    }, 
    {
        "attribution": "AT_101010",
        "recordid": "101010",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry":{
            "coordinates": [5.4933266666669, 43.471325],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties":{
            "label": "BT 456852",
            "latitude": 43.471425,
            "longitude": 5.4933266666669
        }
    },
    {
        "attribution": "AT_104010",
        "recordid": "104010",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry":{
            "coordinates": [5.49339, 43.48],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties":{
            "label": "BT 456852",
            "latitude": 43.48,
            "longitude": 5.49339
        }
    }
]
```

I have an function :

```
createLayersLeaflet(){
    let self = this;
    return leaflet.geoJSON(geoJSONFile,{
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        let iconUrl = ("assets/img/dashboard-icons/map/do.png");
        var smallIcon = leaflet.icon({
            iconUrl: iconUrl,
            iconSize:     [33, 44], 
            iconAnchor:   [16, 44], 
            popupAnchor:  [0, -44]
          });
          return leaflet.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon,attribution: feature.recordid});
        },
      onEachFeature: function (feature,layer){
        var html = '';
            html += '<b>' + feature.properties.label + '</b>';

        layer.bindPopup(html);
      }
    });
  }
```

And i add layers to :

```
self.createfeaturesForLayersLeaflet().addTo(self.map); // self.map is my leaflet.Map
```

I have 2 questions :

1. how can i change the property ‘label’ in  the geoJSON object « AT_104010 » without doing a refresh of all others objects ?
2. how can i change the latitude and longitude position in the geoJSON object « AT_101010 » without doing a refresh of all others objects ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean how to loop through the array of objects, find the ones of interest & updating their values?

Comment: I mean how can i update  the property ‘label’ and change his latitud and longitude for one specific object created by Leaflet after initializing the data with the geoJSON method. 
the update must be understood by Leaflet and displayed on the map. i can remove and recreate but i want juste updated the values.

Comment: When do you want to change these? When for instance clicking a button? Moreover your geojson is not valid. The array of coordinates should contain number and not strings. Use [this](http://geojsonlint.com/) to validate it

Comment: Hi, i have change string=>number thx for the formalization. Trigger action is not important i think but i use :   sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  async _time() {
    await this.sleep(2000);
    this._time();
  }

Comment: My questions are just for action behind the trigger (click mouseover sleep)